# Get other user_ids which have same mid

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search user_id of 1 in table below and get other user_ids related to same mid ( in this case mid of 1 & 3)

```
mid | user_id
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       2
2       3
2       5
3       1
3       5
3       2
```

The result must be :

```
mid | user_id
1       1
1       2
1       3
3       1
3       5
3       2
```

How is it done with MySQL query ?

Comment: because mid 2 has no user_id 1

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to be answered.  It seems you want the following: given a userID, select all mids for that user and then select all users that have those mids... but that's only one interpretation.  Please clarify.

Comment: you are correct Jim..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood correctly, you want to **first** find all mid values that have a user_id value of 1, **then** get all user_id values from all those previously gotten mid values.

```
SELECT mid, user_id from table
where mid IN (SELECT mid FROM table WHERE user_id = 1)
```

Comment: I would change it to `=` rather than `IN` but I do believe that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get all rows for those mid that matches a user_id this should do what you want:

```
select * from your_table t1 
where exists (
  select 1 from your_table t2
  where user_id = 1
  and t1.mid = t2.mid
)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d4bf/2)

Result given your sample data:

```
| MID | USER_ID |
|-----|---------|
|   1 |       1 |
|   1 |       2 |
|   1 |       3 |
|   3 |       1 |
|   3 |       5 |
|   3 |       2 |
```